# explanation for offset resize

Tags: excel, vba

Can you explain to me, what this code will do?
I have to copy some code next to a cell..

Thanks

```
cell.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
ws2.Cells(cell.Row, "C").Resize(1, 3).Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(cell.Row, "C").Resize(1, 3).Value
```

This `cell.Offset(, 2)` will move 0 rows and 2 columns outgoing from `cell` and `.Resize(1, 3)` will then make it 1 row high and 3 columns wide. Into this "selection" it writes the values from `ws2.Cells(cell.Row, "C").Resize(1, 3).Value`

Reading the documentation helps to understand:

- [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)
- [Range.Resize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)